# Fibonacci with huge numbers in c#

Tags: c#, .net, stack-overflow, biginteger, fibonacci

I`m trying to find the first fib number to contain 1000 digits. Because i have no data-type capeable of holding such a number, i created a class called hugeNumber which holds the digits in a list, with a decimal base. I get a stack overflow at the generation of the list for the "hugenum" class - I am not sure why (is it really not the right way to do it? Is there a better way?)

Here's my code:

```
class hugeNum
{
    List<int> digits = new List<int>();
    public hugeNum(int basic)
    {
        digits.Add(basic);
    }
    public hugeNum()
    {
    }
    public static hugeNum operator +(hugeNum first, hugeNum second)
    {
        hugeNum generated = new hugeNum();
        hugeNum finalIter = null;
        int carry = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<second.digits.Count && i<first.digits.Count; i++)
        {
            generated.digits.Add(first.digits[i] + second.digits[i] + carry);
            if (generated.digits[i] >= 10)
            {
                carry = 1;
                generated.digits[i] -= 10;
            }
            else
                carry = 0;
        }
        finalIter = first;
        if (i==first.digits.Count)
        {
            finalIter = second;
        }
        while (i<finalIter.digits.Count)
        {
            generated.digits.Add(finalIter.digits[i]);
            i++;
        }
        return generated;
    }
    public int amountOfDigits()
    {
        return this.digits.Count;
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static int fibHugesUntilIter(hugeNum huge1, hugeNum huge2, int reqDigits, int iter)
    {
        if (huge2.amountOfDigits() == reqDigits)
            return iter;
        return fibHugesUntilIter(huge2, huge1 + huge2, reqDigits, iter + 1);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fibHugesUntilIter(new hugeNum(1), new hugeNum(1), 1000, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What about [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Edit: you are correct, BigInteger is a better structure for my aim, but this is not a project - just a little refresh for me about programming patterns. Thank you for the referance - however , it doesn't seem to be the source of the problem; if you think it is, let me know, i'll reprogram it

Comment: Uhm, what? What makes you think your class won't require a lot of space? I understand that the source of your *current* problem is that you have a bug in your code, but if you don't even *need* that code, shouldn't that be a better fix?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The issue probably isn't inside the implementation of `hugeNum`

Comment: Then that makes this whole question pointless, if the stack overflow is caused by the fact that *something else* filled the stack up, and the call to the list constructor was the proverbial last drop, then this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: This `for (i = 0; i==second.digits.Count && i==first.digits.Count; i++)` looks like a bug.

Comment: Alright, i`ll edit it and return with bigInteger instead, and update you guys about the solution.

Comment: The right way to construct a list is indeed the way that has been chosen in this question. As @Henrik points out, there are other bugs here.

Comment: You don't need recursion to compute Fibonacci numbers.  Just keep track of the last two and calculate the next one in a while loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) without recursion:

```
public static int FibHugesUntil(BigInteger huge1, BigInteger huge2, int reqDigits)
{
    int number = 1;
    while (huge2.ToString().Length < reqDigits)
    {
        var huge3 = huge1 + huge2;
        huge1 = huge2;
        huge2 = huge3;
        number++;
    }
    return number;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(FibHugesUntil(BigInteger.Zero, BigInteger.One, 1000));
}
```

Answer: 4782

Comment: I just solved it myself with Lasse's help a few seconds before you, but sure - this works, here's the checkmark (:

Comment: P.S you forgot the first 2 numbers, iteration should start from 3, the answer is 4782 :)